# git clone from internal gitlab repository doesn't work unless I'm running as root

Tags: linux, git, jenkins, gitlab

I'm trying to clone an internal gitlab repository, but it keeps giving me this error message

```
fatal: unable to access 'https://gitlab**************.git/': gnutls_handshake() failed: Error in the pull function.
```

But somehow, if I'm running as root, the cloning process would run perfectly.

The problem is, I needed this to work because I'm trying to use this repository on Jenkins.

Can someone help me or explain why it only worked if I'm running as root?

Comment: I've seen people associate this with an older version of libcurl. It might be worth doing `which git` and `which curl` as both your normal user and root and see if they're somehow picking up a different version.

Comment: @GregHNZ thanks for your comment, I've tried what you suggested but the output shows that normal and root uses the same version of git and curl. I've also tried compiling git with openssl because I thought gnutls was the issue but it seems that the problem still exist

Answer (score 1):

> root uses the same version of git and curl.

But it does not use the same:

- global git config: compare the output of `git config --global -l` in both instances (root and regular user account).
- environment configuration (type `env` in both cases, and compare the environment variables)

In particular, look for `sslcainfo` (`git config --global -l|grep -i ssl`) which could reference the certificate needed to contact through TLS your on-premise HTTPS GitLab URL.

Comment: thanks for your comment. After following your suggestion, I've found out that the regular user has http proxy env, and the it's proxying my on-premise gitlab url. after removing the proxy the git clone works just fine :D

But apparently, the jenkins that I'm running, which is on minikube still can't access my on-premise gitlab url :(
Which is sad... But oh well Haha
Thanks anyway :D

Comment: @KevinDyandradiva You might need to check if the network route is opened from your Jenkins Minikube session: `curl -v telnet:gitlab**************:443`: is it able to connect to the GitLab server, port 443?